# Expo EAS build failing at install pods

Tags: expo, eas

Expo EAS build is failing at install ios pods step with a pretty nondescript error. I have tried changing node version, image, and legacy deps but it always fails the same way. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Using Expo modules


[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore


Auto-generating `.xcode.env.local` with $NODE_BINARY=/Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node


[stderr]error Failed to load configuration of your project.

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 783: unexpected token at 'info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.'.

 #  from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Podfile:14

 #  -------------------------------------------

 #    use_expo_modules!

 >    config = use_native_modules!


 #  

 #  -------------------------------------------

Error: Unknown error. See logs for more information.
```